# Oracle SQL select query : hierarchical and ranking on "families"

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help for writing a SQL query.

I have a table which looks like this (5 rows example):

```
child      parent
-------------------
CHILD1     PARENT1
CHILD2     PARENT1

CHILD3     PARENT2
CHILD3     PARENT3

CHILD4     PARENT4
```

So a child can have n parents, and a parent can have n children.

I want to be able to calculate a value `INDEX_FAMILY` which counts the number of families. (3 in my example)

It needs some kind of hierarchical query to detect a family (common parents or common children) and a ranking by family.

The end goal is to order by a other table like this :

```
ALL_NAMES
------
PARENT1
CHILD1     
CHILD2     
PARENT2
PARENT3
CHILD3     
PARENT4
CHILD4
```

So we order by family index (based on first table) and then parent first.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions to count the size of each family and, while you probably could use a hierarchical query - it is complicated by only having a single level of parent-child relationships and needing to output both the parent and child in the same column, it appears simpler to use `UNPIVOT` to achieve that and then filtering and ordering:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   (
  SELECT child,
         parent,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parent) AS index_family,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY child) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
UNPIVOT (
  (parent, value) FOR type IN (
    (parent, parent) AS 'P',
    (parent, child) AS 'C'
  )
)
WHERE (type = 'P' AND rn = 1)
OR    type = 'C'
ORDER BY
      index_family DESC,
      parent,
      type DESC,
      rn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (child, parent) AS
SELECT 'CHILD1', 'PARENT1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD2', 'PARENT1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD3', 'PARENT2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD3', 'PARENT3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD4', 'PARENT4' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| PARENT1 |
| CHILD1 |
| CHILD2 |
| PARENT2 |
| CHILD3 |
| PARENT3 |
| CHILD3 |
| PARENT4 |
| CHILD4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3I7QLgEr)

Comment: I dont want to count the size of family but how many there are.

In my example, i have 3 differents families (size doenst matter)

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to calculate a value `INDEX_FAMILY` which counts the number of families. (3 in my example)

If all you want to do is count the number of families then you traverse the hierarchy connecting by either the same parent or the same child and for each root find the minimum reachable row (by some metric, such as the `ROWID` pseudo-column) and then you can `COUNT` the number of `DISTINCT` minimum reachable rows:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MIN(ROWID)) AS index_families
FROM   table_name
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR child = child
OR     PRIOR parent = parent
GROUP BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT ROWID;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (child, parent) AS
SELECT 'CHILD1', 'PARENT1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD2', 'PARENT1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD3', 'PARENT2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD3', 'PARENT3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CHILD4', 'PARENT4' FROM DUAL;
```

Ouputs:

| INDEX_FAMILIES |
| --- |
| 3 |

---

If you combine the hierarchical query used to identify the families with the other answer to the question then you get to:

```sql
SELECT MIN(value) AS value
FROM   (
  SELECT MIN(CONNECT_BY_ROOT child) AS child,
         MIN(CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent) AS parent,
         MIN(ROWID) AS grp
  FROM   table_name
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR child = child
  OR     PRIOR parent = parent
  GROUP BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT ROWID
)
UNPIVOT (
  (parent, value) FOR type IN (
    (parent, parent) AS 'P',
    (parent, child) AS 'C'
  )
)
GROUP BY grp, type, value
ORDER BY grp, type DESC, value;
```

Which outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| PARENT1 |
| CHILD1 |
| CHILD2 |
| PARENT2 |
| PARENT3 |
| CHILD3 |
| PARENT4 |
| CHILD4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zr-YXvnk)